# Working with a public Google spreadsheet (through JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I have a public Google Spreadsheet (editable for everyone with the link).

I would like to use it to store data for a Cordova App.

I believe I could get it to work through Google Apps Script and OAuth.

But then again I wonder, why I have to deal with OAutch if the spreadsheet is public. One use case to avoid OAuth would be, when someone does not even have a Google Account. He can (manually) edit the spreadsheet, so why should I force him to authenticate with OAuth?

So, in essence, how can I read from and write to this spreadsheet without OAuth for the user?

Comment: Thank you very much. I previously only thought about the API Version. I'd accept your comment if it were an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need OAuth in your case. But, you do need to set the settings of the published Web App to be run as "Execute the App As: ME", and "anyone, even anonymous" has access. So, you need to publish the Apps Script as a Web App, "Publish" menu. If you are not going to use Apps Script as a Web App (basically a web site, but you can't get a domain name), then you can just use it as an intermediary between your own app and the spreadsheet. Your app will need to make either a HTTPS GET or POST request to a "doGet()" or "doPost()" function in the Apps Script project.

Comment: also, in that case of using apps script, there is no longer a need to have the spreadsheet be public.